# Can I run multiple faunadb transactions in the one request?

Tags: faunadb

It's possible to have Fauna sequentially execute expressions using `Do`. However, it doesn't work in this particular case:

```
Do(
  CreateCollection({ name: "users" }),
  CreateIndex({
    name: "users_by_email",
    permissions: { read: "public" },
    source: Collection("users"),
    terms: [{field: ["data", "email"]}],
    unique: true
  }) 
)
```

I think this is because "The index [...] may not be created in the same transaction as its source collection(s)." https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/createindex?lang=javascript

How can I efficiently submit my collection and index creation commands together in the one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the title question directly: No. One "request" is a transaction.

However, as you have noted, it is possible to execute multiple FQL expressions in a single transaction, such as your use of the `Do` function.

The reason that the `Do` function doesn't work for your example is that the Fauna query executor performs reads and aggregates write *intentions* as the transaction expression is evaluated, but **all** write effects happen at the end of the transaction. That means that the collection has not been fully written at the time that your `CreateIndex` expression is evaluated, so there is no `Collection("users")` in existence when it is needed.

That is why the warning in the documentation exists. You need to create the collection in one transaction, and the index in another. If you are deploying a known schema, you can create all of your collections in a single transaction, and all of your indexes in a second. That's the best practice answer.

However, it is currently possible with API v4 to make this work by using the `Let` function:

```
Let(
  {
     collection: CreateCollection({ name: "users" }),
     collection_ref: Select("ref", Var("collection")),
  },
  CreateIndex({
    name: "users_by_email",
    source: Var("collection_ref"),
    terms: [{field: ["data", "email"]}],
    unique: true,
  })
)
```

The reason that this works is that the `source` field for an index needs a valid reference. By capturing the result of `CreateCollection` in a named variable, the reference can be be used in the `CreateIndex` expression via the variable.

In the future, the query executor will likely be upgraded to verify the legitimacy of all references provided by variables in the `source` field. If/when that happens, this technique will no longer work. **Use this technique at your own risk**.

Comment: A very detailed answer, thanks! All collections and then all indexes is indeed how I'm doing it now and it works well enough, was just curious if I could speed up my test db creation even further :D